# VIM, SnipMate breaking the undo/redo history

Tags: vim, snipmate

So I recently made the jump over to VIM and I'm still testing out all sorts of plugins. Now, I installed `snipMate` and the snippets work really great, but I'm encountering a strange bug.

When doing `undo / redo` the buffer ends up in pretty strange states.

Before the undo (just some random test coding):

```
conn.on('foo', function(bla, bar, test, foo) {
    conn.foo.hasOwnProperty('test');
    if (true) {

    }
});
```

After the undo:

```
conn.on('foo', function(arguments) {
    conn.foo.hasOwnProperty(  
    if
});
```

As you can see it's completely broken, so the question is, is there any magic I can sprinkle onto the plugin to prevent it from destroying my history? I don't have problem with hacking around in `snipMate` itself.

I already removed all plugins except for `snipMate` to make sure there are no conflicts.

I'm using VIM 7.2, here is my [.vimrc](https://gist.github.com/765071) (yes needs some cleanup...)

Comment: it is not so obvious to me what is "completely broken" ... do you refer to "i triggered 'if<snipmate>' and now it does not remove the 'if' as well"?

Comment: Well it did not remove `if` but it removed part of the line above nameley `'test');`. Simply put: `u` removes things more or less "randomly" when a snippet was used.

Comment: so provide the state 'before snipmate', 'after snipmate' and then 'after undo'; the latter 2 you gave already.

Answer (score 0):

I think have read this issue somewhere else before.
You should try to use the [fork version of garbas on github](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate).
I don't have the issue with this one.
The initial version of msanders is no longer maintained.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for pointing me to the fork, I'll check it out tomorrow :)

Comment: By the way, be careful with the new required package (see readme). Hope this will help!